# How to extends class twice?

Tags: java, subclass, extends

Class passenger will get the number of passenger as well as passengers' information.
Class destination will get the user's choice of destination.
Class transaction will compute the number of passenger and the user's choice of destination.

I extended the class transaction to class destination to know what the user's choice and compute it. But the number of passengers is in the class passenger.

HOW CAN I ACCESS THE VARIABLE NUM FROM THE CLASS PASSENGER TO THE CLASS TRANSACTION?

```
class passenger{

public int num;
public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

void passengerNum(){
    System.out.print("Enter number of Passenger: ");
    **num** = in.nextInt();

    String[] Lname = new String[num];
    String[] Fname = new String[num];
    String[] MI = new String[num];
    String[] Alias = new String[num];
    int[] age = new int[num];
    int underage = 0;

    System.out.println("\nENTER PASSENGER INFORMATION");
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        Lname[i] = in.next();
        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        Fname[i] = in.next();
        System.out.print("Middle Initial: ");
        MI[i] = in.next();
        System.out.print("Alias/Prefix/Suffix: ");
        Alias[i] = in.next();
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        age[i] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();     
}

class destination{

public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static char busClass;
public static char bConvert;

void selectDestination(){

    System.out.print("Select Destination: ");
    passDestination = in.next().charAt(0);
    dConvert = Character.toUpperCase(passDestination);
}
void busClass(){

    System.out.print("Select Bus Class: ");
    busClass = in.next().charAt(0);
    bConvert = Character.toUpperCase(busClass);

}
```

}

```
class transaction extends destination{

public int money;
public double total;
public double change;
public double discount;
public static int AA;

void passengerMoney(){
    System.out.println("Enter payment: ");
    money = in.nextInt();
}

void compute(){
    if(dConvert=='A'){
        if(bConvert=='A'){
            total = AA * num; 
            change = money - total;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Have you researched this at all? You cannot extend a class twice. You may implement multiple interfaces, if that could solve your problem.

Comment: @Pheric I'm just a 1st-year college student, my professor hasn't taught me that. If you don't mind, can you show me how to use implement?

Comment: Here's a link to the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html The answer to your question might be to simply use a public method called a "getter" to get the value of that variable. Then you can store a Passenger inside of a variable in Transaction. That's what the first comment means by "composition." Extending things is probably not the proper way to solve this problem, neither are interfaces. Also, one more thing: please capitalize the first letter of a class name. That's standard practice :)

Comment: By the way (just to be complete), a class cannot extend 2 classes but it can extend a class that extends another class and it will therefore extend both classes (indirectly)

Comment: I would also recommend not making your fields public, but rather private. This gives you control over what object properties can be seen and messed with by other objects, which increases security. At the moment, you can access `num` by having a `passenger` instance and calling `passengerInstance.num`, which isn't best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**create** object of `Passenger class` inside `transaction class`, hence you can access `num` variable of passenger class inside transaction class

**Correction:** inside `transaction class`

```
 Passenger pObject = new Passenger;
           total = AA * pObject.num;
```

**Full code:**

```
public class Passenger{
              public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    public static int num;
                    void passengerNum(){
                        System.out.print("Enter number of Passenger: ");
                        int num = in.nextInt();
                        String[] Lname = new String[num], Fname = new String[num], MI = new String[num], Alias = new String[num];
                        int[] age = new int[num];
                        int underage = 0;

                        System.out.println("\nENTER PASSENGER INFORMATION");
                        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                            System.out.print("Last Name: ");
                            Lname[i] = in.next();
                            System.out.print("First Name: ");
                            Fname[i] = in.next();
                            System.out.print("Middle Initial: ");
                            MI[i] = in.next();
                            System.out.print("Alias/Prefix/Suffix: ");
                            Alias[i] = in.next();
                            System.out.print("Age: ");
                            age[i] = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.println();     
                    }
                }
            }
    public class Destination {
                public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                public static char busClass;
                public static char bConvert;
                void selectDestination(){
                    System.out.print("Select Destination: ");
                }
                char passDestination = in.next().charAt(0), dConvert = Character.toUpperCase(passDestination);
                void busClass(){
                    System.out.print("Select Bus Class: ");
                    busClass = in.next().charAt(0);
                    bConvert = Character.toUpperCase(busClass);
                }
            }
    public class Transaction extends Destination{
                Passenger pObject = new Passenger();
                public int money;
                public double total, change, discount;
                public static int AA;

                void passengerMoney(){
                    System.out.println("Enter payment: ");
                    money = in.nextInt();
                }
                void compute(){
                    if(dConvert=='A'){
                        if(bConvert=='A'){
                            total = AA * pObject.num;
                            change = money - total;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would point out an issue on the design side of your application.

Why would you extend the `destination` with the `transaction` class? Aren't they two distinct entities in the application's logic? 
In this case, is preferable to have an instance of the `destination` class inside the `transaction` class, hence separating the two entities.

Answer (score -1):

> People are giving wrong information -

`In java`, `one class` can be extended any number of times - unlimited times

Like -

```
public  class TestMethod {
    static class A{
        void aMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("aMethod");
        }
    }
    static class B extends A{
        void bMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("bMethod");
        }
    }
    static class C extends B{
        void cMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("cMethod");
        }
    }
    static class D extends C{
        void dMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("dMethod");
        }
    }
    static class E extends D{
        void eMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("eMethod");
        }
    }
    static class F extends E{
        void fMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("fMethod");
        }
    }
    static class G extends F{
        void gMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("gMethod");
        }
    }
    static class H extends G{
        void hMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("hMethod");
        }
    }
    static class I extends H{
        void iMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("iMethod");
        }
    }
    static class J extends I{
        void jMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("jMethod");
        }
    }
    static class K extends J{
        void kMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("kMethod");
        }
    }
    static class L extends K{
        void lMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("lMethod");
        }
    }
    static class M extends L{
        void mMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("mMethod");
        }
    }
    static class N extends M{
        void nMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("nMethod");
        }
    }
    static class O extends N{
        void oMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("oMethod");
        }
    }
    static class P extends O{
        void pMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("pMethod");
        }
    }
    static class Q extends P{
        void qMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("qMethod");
        }
    }
    static class R extends Q{
        void rMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("rMethod");
        }
    }
    static class S extends R{
        void sMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("sMethod");
        }
    }
    static class T extends S{
        void tMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("tMethod");
        }
    }
    static class U extends T{
        void uMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("uMethod");
        }
    }
    static class V extends U{
        void vMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("vMethod");
        }
    }
    static class W extends V{
        void wMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("wMethod");
        }
    }
    static class X extends W{
        void xMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("xMethod");
        }
    }
    static class Y extends X{
        void yMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("yMethod");
        }
    }
    static class Z extends Y{
        void zMethod(int a) {
            System.out.println("zMethod");
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A aobject = new A(); B bobject = new B();C cobject = new C();D dobject = new D();E eobject = new E();F fobject = new F();G gobject = new G();H hobject = new H();I iobject = new I();J jobject = new J();K kobject = new K();L lobject = new L();M mobject = new M();N nobject = new N();O oobject = new O();P pobject = new P();Q qobject = new Q();R robject = new R();S sobject = new S();T tobject = new T();U uobject = new U();V vobject = new V();W wobject = new W();X xobject = new X();Y yobject = new Y();Z zobject = new Z();
    aobject.aMethod(10);bobject.bMethod(10);cobject.cMethod(10);dobject.dMethod(10);eobject.eMethod(10);fobject.fMethod(10);gobject.gMethod(10);hobject.hMethod(10);iobject.iMethod(10);jobject.jMethod(10);kobject.kMethod(10);lobject.lMethod(10);mobject.mMethod(10);nobject.nMethod(10);oobject.oMethod(10);pobject.pMethod(10);qobject.qMethod(10);robject.rMethod(10);sobject.sMethod(10);tobject.tMethod(10);uobject.uMethod(10);vobject.vMethod(10);wobject.wMethod(10);xobject.xMethod(10);yobject.yMethod(10);zobject.zMethod(10);
}
}
```